# Having trouble using GDAX API to place market buy order

Tags: api, python, gdax

[Here](https://github.com/danpaquin/gdax-python) is the documentation I'm following and to place a buy order, the syntax follows the following format:

```
# Buy 0.01 BTC @ 100 USD
auth_client.buy(price='100.00', #USD
               size='0.01', #BTC
               product_id='BTC-USD')
```

That's straight forward but i'd prefer to place a market order using $100 but I'm not sure how.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Set the price to $100 over the current price?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how does the engine resolve orders that are more than adequate? In other words, the seller wants to sell for much less than the buyer wants to buy?